# Recurrence relation with squared term?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How would one solve this recurrence relation?

a(n+1) = $a^2$(n)+ a(n) + 1

Is there a way to use characteristic Polynomials to approach this?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: well... is there a way to solve it regardless?